# How to see the content of the received object?

Tags: java

The function findRecipe returns an object which contains a String name in it, after I captured the returned object and used getName() method to display its String name, but it show null pointer Exception..why? Im first time posting question..sorry if not detail. thank you

```
public class Cookbook {

private Recipe listOfRecipes[] = new Recipe[100];
private static int numberOfRecipes = 0;

public void setListOfRecipes(Recipe a)
{
    listOfRecipes[numberOfRecipes] = a;
    numberOfRecipes++;
}

public Recipe[] getListOfRecipes()
{
    return listOfRecipes;
}

public void addRecipe(Recipe b)
{
    Recipe temp[] = new Recipe[listOfRecipes.length];
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < listOfRecipes.length; i++)
    {
       temp[i] = listOfRecipes[i];  
       count++;
    }

    temp[count] = b;  
}

public Recipe findRecipe(String c)
{
    Recipe temp1 = new Recipe();
    Recipe temp2[] = new Recipe[numberOfRecipes - 1];
    for(int j = 0; j < temp2.length; j++)
    {
    temp2[j] = listOfRecipes[j];
    }

    String a;
    for(int i = 0; i < temp2.length; i++)
    {
        a = temp2[i].getName();
        if(c.equals(a))
        {
          temp1 = temp2[i]; 
        }
        else
        {
          temp1 = null;
        }
    }

    return temp1;
}

public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Recipe butterCake = new Recipe("ButterCake");

    butterCake.setIngredients("3 cup butter");
    butterCake.setIngredients("4 1/2 cup flour");
    butterCake.setIngredients("3 cup sugar");
    butterCake.setIngredients("4 eggs");

    butterCake.setInstructions("Add butter with flour");
    butterCake.setInstructions("Mix butter and flour");
    butterCake.setInstructions("Now add 3 cup sugar");
    butterCake.setInstructions("Mix 4 eggs until yellow pale colour appears");
    butterCake.setInstructions("Bake the mixture for 30 minutes");

    System.out.println(butterCake.getName());
    butterCake.numberOfInstructions();
    butterCake.numberOfIngredients();
    butterCake.showIngredients();
    butterCake.showInstructions();

    Recipe vanillaCake = new Recipe("VanillaCake");

    vanillaCake.setIngredients("3 cup butter");
    vanillaCake.setIngredients("4 1/2 cup flour");
    vanillaCake.setIngredients("3 cup sugar");
    vanillaCake.setIngredients("4 eggs");

    vanillaCake.setInstructions("Add butter with flour");
    vanillaCake.setInstructions("Mix butter and flour");
    vanillaCake.setInstructions("Now add 3 cup sugar");
    vanillaCake.setInstructions("Mix 4 eggs until yellow pale colour appears");
    vanillaCake.setInstructions("Bake the mixture for 30 minutes");

    System.out.println(vanillaCake.getName());
    vanillaCake.numberOfInstructions();
    vanillaCake.numberOfIngredients();
    vanillaCake.showIngredients();
    vanillaCake.showInstructions();

    Cookbook cookBook1 = new Cookbook();

    cookBook1.setListOfRecipes(butterCake);
    cookBook1.setListOfRecipes(vanillaCake);

    Recipe q[] = new Recipe[2];
    q = cookBook1.getListOfRecipes();
    System.out.println(q[0].getName());
    System.out.println(q[1].getName());

    Recipe y = new Recipe();

    y = cookBook1.findRecipe("VanillaCake");

    System.out.println(y.getName()); // ------> GIVING ERROR

  }
}
```

---

```
output :

run:
Name of the Recipe: ButterCake
Number of instructions: 5
Number of ingredients: 4

Ingredients: 
1. 3 cup butter
2. 4 1/2 cup flour
3. 3 cup sugar
4. 4 eggs

Instructions: 
1. Add butter with flour

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
2. Mix butter and flour
3. Now add 3 cup sugar
at Cookbook.main(Cookbook.java:120)
4. Mix 4 eggs until yellow pale colour appears
5. Bake the mixture for 30 minutes
Name of the Recipe: VanillaCake
Number of instructions: 5
Number of ingredients: 4

Ingredients: 
1. 3 cup butter
2. 4 1/2 cup flour
3. 3 cup sugar
4. 4 eggs

Instructions: 
1. Add butter with flour
2. Mix butter and flour
3. Now add 3 cup sugar
4. Mix 4 eggs until yellow pale colour appears
5. Bake the mixture for 30 minutes
Name of the Recipe: ButterCake
Name of the Recipe: VanillaCake
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: `System.out.println(c);` is what you are after? or you want to see content of Reciepe? If not then its not clear what you are after?

Comment: by... printing it in the console? Or creating a web app? Or a Swing app? Or a JavaFX app? Or an Android app?

Comment: `if(temp1 != null) System.out.println(temp1.someMember)` ?

Comment: Run it in the debugger and set a breakpoint?

Comment: Before anyone can efficiently help you, we need more information. Are you asking how to see the content of the returned item temp1?

Comment: The function returns an object which contains a String name in it, after I captured the returned object and used getName() method to display its String name, but it show null pointer Exception..why?

Comment: @KuganKumar - Where is your  listOfRecipes[j] array declared?

Comment: @Kugankumar Check if the returned object is `null`

Comment: it declared inside the same class

Comment: this is my first time here..

Comment: @KuganKumar if you ask about an exception, then make that clear in your question instead of letting us guess after 10 comments. And ALWAYS include the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @kugankumar You should `break` once you have found a match in `findRecipe` method

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1:** You are not breaking once you find a match. So only time you will return a non-null value is when a match occurs at last index.

**Solution:** Add `break` once a match is found.

**Problem 2:** Your `getName` function in class `Recipe` returns as `Name of the Recipe: RECIPE NAME`

**Solution:** Either change the way `getName` returns the name of recipe (get rid of `Name of the Recipe:` )or change the way you call.

Modified `for loop` in function `getRecipe`

```
String a;  
temp1=null;
for(int i = 0; i < temp2.length; i++)
{
    a = temp2[i].getName();
    if(c.equals(a))
    {
      temp1 = temp2[i]; 
      break; //<----------
    }
    else
    {
      temp1 = null;
    }
}

 return temp1;
}
```

Call this function as (in main)

```
y = cookBook1.findRecipe("Name of the Recipe: VanillaCake");
```